# Успешный человек

Tags: грамотная-речь

Любимая тема психологов - это сделать из нормального человека "успешного". Но сейчас не об этом, а о том, насколько вообще грамматически верно выражение "успешный человек"?
Я всегда считала, что успешным может быть какое-то дело, но никак не объект. Можно ли вообще по отношению к человеку сказать, что человек успешный, а не добившийся успеха, или это полностью искусственная конструкция?

Comment: искусственная конструкция, Вы правы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Словообразование: успех - успешный, где суффикс Н - один из самых регулярных и продуктивных суффиксов, он образует прилагательные с общим значением признака или свойства, относящегося к предмету, лицу, явлению, действию и т.д.

Поэтому успешным можно назвать и дело, и человека. До недавнего времени это слово не было в ходу, и в словаре оно числится как разговорное, но сейчас становится очень популярным, даже дискуссии проводятся на тему "Успешный человек: какой он?",   настолько  актуален вопрос успешности для наших современников.

А значение у слова "успешный", действительно, "склонный к успеху", а не "имеющий успех", чем оно и отличается от "успешных дел".

Comment: "склонный к успеху"... Смешно. Так и до склонности к победе недалеко, к триумфу. Разве много таких, обречённых опережать других раз за разом, что б всерьёз говорить о стабильности и гарантированном успехе? Нет, конечно. Склонный - заряженный, увлечённый, способный. Добивающийся  успеха - успевающий, преуспевающий. Добившийся - преуспевший. 

"Успешный" в отношении к человеку не применял бы, только к его делам.

Answer (score 4):

Такое словосочетание вполне корректно. У слова "успешный" одно из значений является: такой, которому сопутствует успех  в чем-л. Успешный сотрудник.

> УСПЕШНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -шен, -шна, -шно.
> 1.
> Заключающий в себе успех, сопровождающийся успехом. У-ые гастроли. У-ые занятия. У-ая работа. У. исход дела. У-ые оценки. У-ая охота. У-ая демонстрация новых моделей одежды.
> 2. Разг.
> Такой, которому сопутствует успех в чём-л. У. сотрудник. У. обманщик.
> ***Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
> Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.***

Answer (score 2):

Успешный человек - это не совсем "человек, добившийся успеха" - под последним можно понимать нечто однократное или внешнее (известность). Под "успешным человеком" чаще понимают такое свойство характера человека, как способность систематически осуществлять собственные замыслы, реалистично оценивая свои силы. Это противоположность понятия "неудачник", независимо от того, на каком уровне компетентности и в какой сфере деятельности первое или второе проявляется.

Comment: Под "успешным человеком" чаще понимают свойство характера человека? Под человеком понимают свойство? Как правильно это понять?

Comment: Конечно, требует правки, но понять нетрудно. Под "успешным человеком" чаще понимают человека с таким свойством характера, как способность систематически осуществлять собственные замыслы, реалистично оценивая свои силы.